# JSON has extra quotations and slashes

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**EDIT:** This isn't a duplicate of the mentioned question because the main issue isn't the extra slashes - it's the extra quotation marks that can't be removed with a single replaceAll.

I use the following code to convert my FCM response into JSON format:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    try
    {
        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

        if(params != null)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params);
            Object notificationObject = parseJson(jsonObject.toString());

            if(notificationObject instanceof ClientRequestAcceptedModel)
           {
                Log.d(TAG, ((ClientRequestAcceptedModel) notificationObject).getFeedback());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I get the following:**

```
{
    "notification_type": "request_accepted",
    "partner_information": "{\"zip\":\"24000\",\"country\":\"canada\",\"address\":\"any raw address\",\"city\":\"some-city\",\"device_meta\":{\"device_id\":\"av0384yuhyiush23768\",\"device_type\":\"android\"},\"last_name\":\"Ahmed1\",\"created_at\":\"2018-04-04 16:28:59\",\"avatar\":\"some image path\",\"partner\":1,\"password_hash\":\"yasir123\",\"last_modefied\":\"2018-04-04 16:28:59\",\"phone_number\":\"+921234567890\",\"location\":{\"latitude\":\"1234567\",\"longitude\":\"1234567\"},\"id\":2,\"first_name\":\"Yasir1\",\"email\":\"yasirahmed15@yopmail.com\",\"customer\":1,\"status\":1}",
    "feedback": "request accepted",
    "request_information": "{\"request_type\":\"custom\",\"request_quotation\":true,\"created_at\":\"2018-05-07 15:57:13\",\"media\":[{\"body\":\"base64string\",\"type\":\"image\"},{\"body\":\"base64string\",\"type\":\"video\"},{\"body\":\"base64string\",\"type\":\"audio\"}],\"schedule_date\":\"0000-00-00\",\"client_id\":2,\"pStatus\":0,\"partner_id\":2,\"schedule_time_from\":\"00:00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\",\"schedule_time_to\":\"00:00:00\",\"skill\":{\"name\":\"Pipe Fitting\",\"id\":\"1\"},\"extra_notes\":\"some extra notes\",\"request_location\":{\"address\":\"Some raw address of the client if any\",\"latitude\":\"1234567\",\"longitude\":\"1234567\"},\"id\":23,\"status\":0}"
}
```

As you can see, there are a ton of extra **\ (slashes)** and some extra **" (quotes)**. I have to use the following to convert it into valid JSON:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params);
String modifier = jsonObject.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");
String modifier2 = modifier.replace("\"{\"", "{\"");
String modifier3 = modifier2.replace("}\"", "}");
```

*Is there any way to properly do this?* I can't be looking at all JSON and looking for things to replace/fix.

**EDIT: Here are the objects**

```
public class ClientRequestAcceptedModel
{
    @Json(name = "feedback") private String feedback;
    @Json(name = "partner_information") private UserModel partnerInformation;
    @Json(name = "request_information") private RequestInformationModel requestInformation;
}

public class RequestInformationModel
{
    @Json(name = "id") private String id;
    @Json(name = "client_id") private String clientId;
    @Json(name = "partner_id") private String partnerId;
    @Json(name = "skill_id") private String skillId;
    @Json(name = "latitude") private String latitude;
    @Json(name = "longitude") private String longitude;
    @Json(name = "address") private String address;
    @Json(name = "request_type") private String requestType;
    @Json(name = "request_quotation") private Boolean requestQuotation;
    @Json(name = "extra_notes") private String extraNotes;
    @Json(name = "status") private String status;
    @Json(name = "created_at") private String createdAt;
    @Json(name = "updated_at") private String updatedAt;
    @Json(name = "pStatus") private String pStatus;
}
```

EDIT: Adding model requested by a user below

```
    public class RequestInformationModelAdapter extends JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel>
{
    @Override
    public RequestInformationModel fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(RequestInformationModel.class);

        return jsonAdapter.fromJson(reader.nextString());
    }

    @Override
    public void toJson(JsonWriter writer, RequestInformationModel value) throws IOException
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(RequestInformationModel.class);

        writer.value(jsonAdapter.toJson(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to print `jsonObject` in log

Comment: No, I got its value via the debugger.

Comment: @NileshRathod And this isn't a duplicate. Removing slashes isn't the main issue, its the quotation marks.

Comment: Whatever your data class is, it's incorrect. Or the backend is sending escaped json values for partner_information and request_information. Doesn't look like you're even using Moshi.

Also, you shouldn't be using an Object class like that, and instanceof is a code smell.

Comment: @AfzalivE added the classes. The UserModel class is fine (it is already being used elsewhere and works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonString)` is called, it converts all the types that match automatically, and for types that don't match automatically (like a String instead of a nested JsonObject), it will throw an exception. So you need to tell it how to convert from that String to a custom type using the custom adapter.

Now you should be able to do the other one yourself.

```
    Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(RequestInformationModel.class, new RequestInformationModelAdapter()).build();
    JsonAdapter<ClientRequestAcceptedModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(ClientRequestAcceptedModel.class);

    ClientRequestAcceptedModel clientRequestAccepted;
    try {
        clientRequestAccepted = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
        System.out.println(clientRequestAccepted);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This class below is responsible for converting the nested json to RequestInformationModel. You have to tell moshi again which class to convert this string to.

```
    public class RequestInformationModelAdapter extends JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel> {

        @Override
        public RequestInformationModel fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
            JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(RequestInformationModel.class);

            return jsonAdapter.fromJson(reader.nextString());
        }

        @Override
        public void toJson(JsonWriter writer, RequestInformationModel value) throws IOException {
            Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
            JsonAdapter<RequestInformationModel> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(RequestInformationModel.class);

            writer.value(jsonAdapter.toJson(value));
        }
    }
```

You really should've tried to use Moshi first. Your example in the question doesn't even utilize it.

Comment: I tried the code you provided. Doesn't work. I'm given the same "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $.partner_information"

Comment: The problem occurs before Moshi is used which is why I didn't add that code. The 'String' that I get from jsonObject.toString() has extra quotations and slashes. They are the issue, not the subsequent parsing.

Comment: That&#39;s because you have to do the same thing (with a custom adapter) for partner information.

I&#39;ve already said this, you have a malformed json which isn&#39;t nested properly. Either fix the json on the backend or use one of the solutions provided in the answers.

The error spells it out clearly, it's expecting a json object for partner information and the json only has a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Wrote a similar Adapter for the other model and it worked. Marking your answer correct.

Comment: @chitgoks Sure, added to question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Moshi, but from what I'm seeing, it's serializing `partner_information` and `request_information` as `String` instead of `JSONbject`. Check your parent model configuration to see if the annotations are correct.

Comment: They're properly annotated.

Comment: Can you share the actual parent model that you're trying to serialize?

Comment: Added the objects.